# Django logging - for local development

Tags: python, django

I been trying to configure logging in django properly for development so I can just see it in the console for now, but when I change from print to logging then the output just doesn't appear.

django local settings setup:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
        },
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': sys.stdout

        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'myapp.management': {
            'handlers': [
                # 'mail_admins',
                # 'syslog',
                'console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': [
                # 'mail_admins',
                # 'syslog',
                'console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
    }
}
```

Then in a django management command:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Using the logger via:

```
def collect_data(self, url, method, payload=None):
        response = getattr(requests, method)(url=url json=payload, headers=self.headers)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            logging.debug('{}'.format(response.json())
            # print('{}'.format(response.json()))
            return response.json()
        else:
            logging.warning('{}'.format(response.raise_for_status()))
            # print('{}'.format(response.raise_for_status()))
            return response.raise_for_status()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file named test.py inside your management folder, you would configure it this way:

```
'testproject.management.commands.test': {
            'handlers': ['my_handler'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True
        },
```

The imports inside test.py are okay like this:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Haven't exactly tested it out right this moment, but this is from a project of mine where I was using a logger inside a management command and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks bizarrely I can get some output with `logging.info('some string')` at some points in my management command script but not others. At the points where it doesn't work a `print('some string')` right next to the logging works. I get no errors so I have no clue why it works in some places but not others?

Comment: Can you post the entire file?